# tar exiting with no message, not extracting archive, and exit status 0

Tags: bash, tar

I'm trying to use the following line to extract the first file in a directory:

```
tar xzvf `ls -1 | head -n1 | tail -1` --force-local
```

For some reason, tar simply exits without throwing an error and without creating the archive.  If I manually type the filename, it works fine.

The only potential issue I can see is that my filenames contain colons.  Still, I have tried doing the same thing with mv and everything worked:

```
mv `ls -1 | head -n1 | tail -1` newfile
```

And the file is renamed properly.

Any idea what may be the issue, or how I can further debug this?

Comment: The `tar` command you list assumes that the first file in an alphabetic listing of the current directory is a compressed tar-file, and tries to extract that. If, in fact, that file is a proper archive, how was it created? Do the files inside have absolute path names, relative path names, or no path names? Is it possibly an empty file or empty archive?

Comment: that file has to be a legitimate gzip'd tar file. check the file content.

Comment: It is a legitimate gzipped file.  Like I said, if I manually type the filename into the command it all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tar file was ultimately not a proper tar file.  I was typing the filename wrong.  If you are having a similar issue, check to ensure the file isn't blank or of another content type.

Comment: Put another way: check yourself before you wreck yourself.